# Why is each character displayed on a new line/row?

Tags: php, chart.js

When inserting the result of my php on the chart, it separates each number on to a new row.
That is, if there is 120, It separates 1, 2 and 0. Each on a new line.

What was my mistake?
My code:

```
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" height="100%"></canvas>
</div>
    <script>
        var lineChartData = {
            labels :[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],

            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data :
                    <?php
while($valor = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    extract($valor);
    $pingresposta.= $valor['resposta'];
    $pinghorario.= $valor['horario'];
}
echo json_encode($pingresposta);
?>

                }
            ]

        }

    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true

        });
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `datasets.data` is expecting an array to be used, but `json_encode` is returning a string. In javascript, strings can be iterated per character and have a length just like arrays... so the duck quacked and no error occurred.

You'll need to use `JSON.parse` on the echo'd PHP output if you're going to json_encode and ensure it's an array before sending it to the graph to be parsed.

Update:

Try this instead.

```
<?php
$graphdata = array();
while($valor = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    extract($valor);
    $graphdata[] = $valor['resposta'];
}

echo '[' . implode(',', $graphdata) . ']';
?>
```

Comment: @ADHenrique can you provide some sample data as to what `extract($valor);` and `$pingresposta` look like? It's hard to tell when you're referencing variables that I don't know the structure of.

Comment: @ADHenrique what do you get when you `print_r($pingresposta);` after the `while` loop?

Comment: You can see the full code here: [Link](http://www.adhenrique.com.br/somcap/code.txt)

Comment: Owwwwwwww man.
It worked perfectly.
The problem would be `implode` ?? '

Comment: @ADHenrique What I've done is taken each piece of data and stored it in an array called `$graphdata`. The `implode` function is an array utility that concatenates an array into a string, with a defined separator. You can read more about it here: http://php.net/IMPLODE

Comment: @ADHenrique in the end the output will result in `[data1, data2, data3]` in your javascript.

Comment: OMG, you can be sure I'll read more about it. (I'm starting in development)
Thank you, thank you very very much. You solved my problem.
Hugs.

Comment: @ADHenrique no problem, if you could mark the answer as 'correct' that would be great. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some stray characters from the query results?
Try

```
$pingresposta.= trim($valor['resposta']);
$pinghorario.= trim($valor['horario']);
```